# PHP: JSON file format checker in PHP?

Tags: php, json

We get a daily feed downloaded which is in JSON file format. From there a series of scripts parse the JSON file. However, I want to make the process more robust and have it check to make sure the downloaded file is indeed in JSON format before it proceeds. It might not be in JSON format for several reasons such as a data transmission problem or someone put the wrong file in there for us to download. Either way, I would like to be able to check the file and verify it is in JSON file format before proceeding with the parsing scripts.

Is there a PHP method to verify that a file is in JSON format? Thanks!

Would this do?

```
// Returns True if JSON data is good, false if bad.
function isJson($string) {
 json_decode($string);
 return (json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE);
}

// invalid JSON data
$json = 'blablabla{"user_id":14,"username":"flow"}]foobar';
if(isJson($json)) 
{
        echo "good" . "\n";
        }
else {
        echo "bad" . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) already validates the input: if it's invalid, it returns `null`.

In the unlikely case that you want to differentiate between invalid input and `"null"` (i.e. the JSON representation of `null`), you can perform an additional check manually:

```
if(stricmp(trim($input), "null") == 0) {
    // $input is a json representation of null
}
```

Comment: I see. Could I just as well check if json_decode($string) is false?

Comment: @Edward: Check how exactly and for what purpose? Did you read the function documentation?

Comment: This way:
// Returns True is JSON data is good, false if bad.
function isJson($string) {
 json_decode($string);
 return (json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE);
}

Comment: Then check if isJson($json) is false, then the data isn't in JSON format.

Comment: @Edward: Yes, that's fine. My only gripe is that in effect you are throwing away the result of the parse (and presumably will then parse again). But it's very clear.

Comment: @Jon Hmm...what is wrong with throwing away the result of the parse? I'm only interested to check to see if it's bad data. Thanks!

Comment: @Edward: If you don't need the result at all then no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use jsonlint: https://github.com/zaach/jsonlint
It can do much more, but also is a validator